# Converting JSON response observable to angular (typescript) object array

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have a service API that pulls data from Django-REST. The returned JSON looks like:

```
[
{
    "manufacturer": "Mfg",
    "model": "Model",
},
{
    "manufacturer": "Mfg2",
    "model": "Model2",
}
]
```

The service API function `getData` returns:

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiURL}/data/`);
```

Note I am using ListAPIView in Django, and I have verified that the above URL returns the JSON object shown above (though I have to add ?format=json to get the raw data outside of Django's APIView).

I then have an angular component that calls the service API function to convert the observable to an array of objects:

```
export class Data implements OnInit {

private records = Array<object> = [];

...

constructor(private  apiService:  ApiService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
}

public getData() {
 this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {this.records = data});
```

There are no error or warnings, but in the component's HTML file when I try to access the record array it always has a length of 0. For example, the following will print "0" and an empty table.

```
<P> {{ records.length }}</P>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Manufacturer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let record of records">
    <td> {{ record.manufacturer }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to assign data into objects without parsing. Can you provide a demo?

Comment: parse your data using JSON.parse(data), if its stringified from the server side.

Comment: don't assign Array<object> = [] into your records variable just declare it and it will be work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define a model using an interface, and then use that interface as a generic parameter to the get call, the HttpClient will automatically map the response to the defined structure.

For example:

**Interface**

```
export interface Product {
  manufacturer: string;
  model: string;
}
```

**Data Service**

```
return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(`${this.apiURL}/data/`);
```

**Component**

```
private records: Product[];

public getData() {
 this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data: Product[]) => this.records = data);
}
```

EDIT: If you want to add a console.log to the above, you need to add it like this:

```
public getData() {
 this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
     this.records = data;
     console.log(this.records);
  );
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="records">
 <p> {{ records.length }}</p>
 ...
</div>
```

When the template first appears, the async data retrieval process may not yet have finished. So by putting an `ngIf` around the page, it won't attempt to display the elements until the data is retrieved.

Comment: Hello , 

when i console log in ` this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data: Product[]) => this.records = data);
`   , then it still in `Object` type not in Product[] type and it is not workin. Can you please update answer . Thankk you

Comment: See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the async pipe to it.

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records|async">
    <td> {{ record.manufacturer }} </td>
  </tr>
```