# How to parse the Json array from Json object using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular8

In angular application I have called the API and read  the Json object inconsole .But inside the Json object there is string and array.Now I have to parse the array from the object incosole.

The object I have got in console is:

```
{
"Drone": {
    "Droneid": 1001,
    "latlong": [
        {
            "lat": 12.989839,
            "lon": 80.198822
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.051832,
            "lon": 80.194480
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.038453,
            "lon": 80.227442
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.009018,
            "lon": 80.242550
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.976903,
            "lon": 80.237056
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.956829,
            "lon": 80.193107
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.980917,
            "lon": 80.150531
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.007680,
            "lon": 80.149158
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.043805,
            "lon": 80.154651
        }
    ]
}
}
```

But I have to parse latlong array from the object.

**Dashboard.service.ts**

```
mapping(token){
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    })
  };
  //this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
    this.http.get(environment.apiurl +'/api/data/json', httpOptions).subscribe(  
    (dronesdt:any)=>{
      localStorage.setItem("dronesdt",JSON.stringify(dronesdt));
      console.log("Drones",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dronesdt")));
 } 
  )
}
```

So how can I get the latlong array in console.
Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: Try `console.log(dronesdt.Drone.latlong);`

Comment: Have you tried declaring interfaces to represent your structure and using the generic version of `get` => `this.http.get<Drone>(...)`?

Comment: No,I have not involved in this area before can you please help me to represent the structure of the required json object..and my goal is receive the latlong array from the object.

Comment: There are multiple tutorials/answers to be found regarding this topic, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625967/converting-json-response-observable-to-angular-typescript-object-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `latlong` field like this:

**dashboard.service.ts**

```js
mapping(token){
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    })
  };
  // this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(
    this.http.get(environment.apiurl +'/api/data/json', httpOptions).subscribe(  
    (dronesdt:unknown /*Try to avoid any and statically type values as far as possible*/)=>{
      localStorage.setItem("dronesdt",JSON.stringify(dronesdt));
      console.log("Drones", dronesdt.Drone.latlong);
 } 
  // )
}
```

There is no need to `JSON.parse` the object in the console since you have already fetched the latest data right in that function.